# Cellular homology with attaching maps of varying degrees.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am studying for a qualifying exam in point set and algebraic topology and am struggling with this question from a past exam.

Let $Z = \mathbb{C} -\{\pm 1\}$ and let $X$ be the space obtained from $Z$ by attaching three disks via the maps $f_1 = z^4 +1$, $f_2 = z^6 -1$, and $f_3=2z$.

We are allowed to use without proof that $Z$ deformation retracts to $S^1 \vee S^1$. I first gave $X$ a CW decomposition into one $0$-cell (say $v$), two $1$-cells ($a$ and $b$), and three $2$-cells ($U$, $L$, and $R$). Since there is only one $0$-cell, we know $d_1=0$. I am struggling with computing $d_2$.

My first question is relating the degree to the generators. Is $z^4$ equivalent to $a^4b^4$ and $2z$ to $ab$? Do I need to do anything with the $+1$ after the $z^4$ or the $2$ in front of the $z$?

After reading comments, I believe $d_2$ must be
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: For question 1 you need to figure out what each map does to the unit circle and how many times it wraps around each hole in $Z$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thank you for responding! My guess is that $f_1$ wraps around the first hole 4 times (judging by the +1), $f_2$ wraps around the second hole 6 times, and $f_3$ wraps around each hole once.  Is this correct?

Comment: indeed.$\hspace{1em}$

Comment: What do you mean by attaching map? If I guess correctly, you mean that the point $z$ on the disk becomes identified with the point $f(z)$ in $Z$, is this correct? If so, what do you attach the point $z=1/2$ of the third disk to?

Comment: @carciofo21 The attaching map is the map $f_i: \partial D^2 \to Z$ that glues the boundary to a $1$-cell in $Z$. It sounds like you glue one half of the third disk to each one-cell, but I'm still unclear why this is true. Is it because of the $2z$? If it were just $z$, you'd only attach it to one $1$-cell?